# Linq to Sql using a non-column attribute property in Association attribute

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create an association between 2 linq to sql entities, say Entity A and Entity B.
 A uses a non-column attribute property ( named BaseDocumentType ) and a column attribute in an Association for "ThisKey" and 2 column attributes for "OtherKey".  The following is an example of my Association attribute definition...
**[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute ( ... ThisKey = "BaseDocumentType, Column2" , OtherKey = "Column1,Column2" )]**

When I run it I get the following error...
"Data member 'System.String BaseDocumentType' of type 'Library' is not part of the mapping for type 'A'. Is the member above the root of an inheritance hierarchy?"

How can I define the relationship using the non-column attribute property or how do I make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem here is that your inheritance model doesn't work nicely with LINQ to SQL. If you could add information about the table(s) and entities that leverage the inheritance model, we may be able to offer some other alternatives. Initially, I would say your BaseDocumentType might be better as an Interface rather than base class because I doubt your EntityA and EntityB are subtypes of BaseDocumentType, but rather implement a IDocumentType interface. EF does support the mapping you want, but the perf may be less than desired.

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear. LINQ to SQL translates statements to SQL and you tried to use a property that doesn't map to a column, so it can't be translated to SQL.

You'll have to retrieve the entities you want from the database then try to query them using LINQ to Objects, ie LINQ operations on the resulting lists or arrays. A better option is to rethink your design and find a way to retrieve only the data you need from the database and avoid processing the results on the client.

Linq to SQL in this case prevented you from doing something really dangerous. It could have retrieved all the data and process them using your non-column attribute but that would create an enormous performance hit. Some naive LINQ providers actually do just that. Imagine retrieving 1000 objects from the database only to find the two objects that match over this non-column attribute.